# How to install sqlectron GUI in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, postgresql

I am new to ubuntu and am trying to install sqlectron. I have downloaded the GUI application from the below link https://sqlectron.github.io/

I don't see any steps anywhere for installing GUI application, do we have a GUI version for ubuntu? 
I only want the GUI version and not the Terminal one.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can install `Sqlectron_1.30.0_amd64.deb` from the link below.
`https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/releases`

Move to the directory you installed, and run `sudo gdebi Sqlectron_1.30.0_amd64.deb` to complete the installation.

Good Luck!!

Comment: Sqlectron is no longer maintained, but if you are still looking for an open source SQL client you can check out beekeeperstudio.io - it picks up where Sqlectron has left off

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest deb package from here: https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/releases/tag/v1.36.0

After downloading, use the below command to install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i sqlectron_1.36.0_amd64.deb
```

Hope this helps!